Warning - Unable move and reuse existing repository to required location
I have a pipeline in which I am carrying out two checkout tasks.
- checkout: ${{ parameters.repository_resource }}
  displayName: checkout ${{ parameters.repository_resource }}
  path: 's'

- checkout: self
  displayName: checkout repository
  path: "mydirectory"

However, the issue I get is a warning in my pipeline in regards to the 2nd checkout:

Repository is current at '/home/vsts/work/1/s/poc-plan-in-pr', move to '/home/vsts/work/1/cibuild'
##[warning]Unable move and reuse existing repository to required location.

Both checkouts are happening, and my pipeline does still work, indicating that it is retrieving the git repos successfully—but for some reason this warning won't go away.
So I guess the pipeline does work, but this is annoying

This question is similar to: How to avoid "Unable move and reuse existing repository to required location" warning?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Based on your description, I could reproduce the warning when any of the repos was checked out directly into the $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) which was the s folder under $(Agent.BuildDirectory).
According to the document on Checkout path, you may either consider not adding the path properties for the checkout steps, so that the repos will be checked out into directories named after the repositories as a subfolder of s in $(Agent.BuildDirectory).
parameters:
- name: repository_resource
  default: 'Repo1'

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: Repo1
    name: Repo1
    type: git

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  repository_resource_name: $[ resources.repositories.Repo1.name ]

steps:
- checkout: ${{ parameters.repository_resource }}
  displayName: checkout ${{ parameters.repository_resource }}
  # path: $(repository_resource_name)

- checkout: self
  displayName: checkout repository
  # path: cibuild

- bash: tree $(Agent.BuildDirectory)

Or, you may add the path properties but avoid using the s directory, so that the paths are used relative to $(Agent.BuildDirectory).
parameters:
- name: repository_resource
  default: 'Repo1'

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: Repo1
    name: Repo1
    type: git

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  repository_resource_name: $[ resources.repositories.Repo1.name ]

steps:
- checkout: ${{ parameters.repository_resource }}
  displayName: checkout ${{ parameters.repository_resource }}
  path: $(repository_resource_name)

- checkout: self
  displayName: checkout repository
  path: cibuild

- bash: tree $(Agent.BuildDirectory)


Thanks for your advice- from what i understand of your comment, you're suggesting i don't specify paths, and both checkouts will be checkedout to 's/repository_resource' and 's/self' respectively. The issue i have is i specifically wanted these to end up at my specified paths, as this code block is part of a much larger pipeline template, and other paths require me to alter lots of my code elsewhere

Have you got a chance to check the link in my answer? When checking out a single repo, the $(Agent.BuildDirectory)/s is the set as the default path to the root repo. When checking out multiple repos, the $(Agent.BuildDirectory)/s/SubfoldersNamedAfterRepoNames are the default paths to those repos. Based on the definition in your original post, I could reproduce the warning when the repo resource was checked out to path: 's', as s was the parent folder of the default checkout path s/SubfoldersNamedAfterRepoNames and it did generate the warning but wouldn't fail the step.

I also suggested you define other path that s, which would checkout the repo resource to the path like $(Agent.BuildDirectory)/poc-plan-in-pr instead of $(Agent.BuildDirectory)/s

My understanding of git checkout was that if I specified the path I wanted my repo to end up at, it checks it out directly to there.
However, after some fiddling around, I have now discovered the solution to this problem.
It is that even though I have specified the path: cibuild, inline with the error, I actually had to create the /home/vsts/work/1/s/poc-plan-in-pr directory myself manually.
- pwsh: |
          New-Item -Path "$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/$(Build.Repository.Name)" -ItemType "directory" -Force
        displayName: "pr step: prepare checkout"
      - checkout: self
        displayName: "pr step: checkout repository"
        path: "cibuild"

